# Using CCSchedulers/CCTimers in Cocos2d Project

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, nsobject

I have a GameController object, which is meant to manage stuff like the scores.

The score is based on how long the user has played, so I want to increase the score by one every 2 seconds. So my GameController is a subclass of NSObject, and I'm trying to use a CCTimer or CCScheduler (CCTimer seems to be depreciated?) But using this line, the method never fires:

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(updateNaturalScore:) forTarget:self interval:1 paused:NO];
```

Do I have to user this in a Cocos2d object? If so which one? Or should it work in an NSObject subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a cocos2D project?
have you tried [NSTimer scheduleTimer...];
it will work for your purpose, for the method not getting fired, the class being NSObject how is it accessing the classes from Cocos2D framework? Has the method written in the same class?